# JavaScript - How to know which object has been clicked

Tags: javascript

I have a basic film search, now I'm trying to make it so that once you click on a film, it gets just that clicked films title property, at the moment it is bringing every film from the list of films that match the search term.

How do I go about finding out which film has been clicked and ONLY pass this objects properties through instead of every object? Do I need to use a loop?

screenshots added, e.g if I click the first film "John Wick" it creates a h1 title for every film title that has "John Wick"

```js
function search() {
    var userInput = $("#content-container-search").val().replace(/\s+/g,"%20");
    var searchTerm = "".concat(standardURL, apiKey, 'query=', userInput);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    clear(); //runs the clear function to clear existing DOM results to make way for the new ones
    
    request.open('GET', searchTerm , true);
    request.onload = function(data) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        
        createList(data);
    }
    
request.send();
}

function createList(data){
    var app = document.getElementById("film-results");
    
    data.results.forEach(film => {
            console.log(film.title);
            var filmInfo = film;

            var Filmcontainer = document.createElement("div");
        Filmcontainer.setAttribute("class", "row film-container");
        
        var filmContainerLeftPanel = document.createElement("div");
        filmContainerLeftPanel.setAttribute("class", "film-container-left-panel column small-3");
        
        var filmContainerRightPanel = document.createElement("div");
        filmContainerRightPanel.setAttribute("class", "film-container-right-panel column small-9");
        
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.setAttribute("class", "film-container-right-panel-li");
        
        var ul = document.createElement("ul");
        
        var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
        h1.setAttribute("class", "film-container-right-panel-h1");
        h1.textContent = film.title;
        
        var ahref = document.createElement("a");
//            ahref.setAttribute("class", "button");
        ahref.setAttribute("data-open", "exampleModal1");
    
        var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
        paragraph.setAttribute("class", "film-container-right-panel-p");
        
        var paragraphMaxLength = 125;
        var filmOverview = film.overview;
        var trimmedFilmOverview = filmOverview.substr(0, paragraphMaxLength);
        trimmedFilmOverview = trimmedFilmOverview.substr(0, Math.min(trimmedFilmOverview.length, trimmedFilmOverview.lastIndexOf(" ")));
        trimmedFilmOverview = trimmedFilmOverview + "...";
       
    
        paragraph.textContent = trimmedFilmOverview;
        
        var baseImgURL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154" + film.poster_path;
           
        var filmImage = document.createElement("img");
        filmImage.src = baseImgURL;
        filmImage.setAttribute("class", "film-container-right-panel-img");
        
//            film.forEach(filmImage.src.indexOf("null"))
//             filmImage.src = "/img/imagenotavailable.png";
    
        app.appendChild(Filmcontainer);
        Filmcontainer.appendChild(filmContainerLeftPanel);
        Filmcontainer.appendChild(filmContainerRightPanel);
        
        filmContainerLeftPanel.appendChild(filmImage);
        filmContainerRightPanel.appendChild(ul)
        .appendChild(li)
        .appendChild(ahref)
        .appendChild(h1);
        li.appendChild(paragraph);   


    generateModal(filmInfo);
        })
           
}


function generateModal(filmInfo){
    
        var modal = document.getElementById("exampleModal1");
        var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
        h1.textContent = filmInfo.title;
        modal.appendChild(h1);
        
        console.log(filmInfo);

}
```

[image: search]
[image: modal]
[image: film objects]

Comment: [mcve]..........

Comment: Please show the part of the code when you listen for the click event.

Comment: Possibly pass "this" to the function? Then look at the innerhtml to determine which one it is?

Comment: Include the HTML in your example so we have an idea what you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to take a look at [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) and [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

--UPDATE--

Here is an example:

```js
let ctas = document.querySelectorAll('.see-details');

ctas.forEach(cta => {
  cta.addEventListener('click', (movie) => {
    let movieId = movie.target.getAttribute('data-movie-id');
    
    console.log(movieId);
  });
});
```

```html
<button data-movie-id="toy-story-1" class="see-details">See movie details</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) in JavaScript.

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(div);

var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "John Wick";
button.style.margin= "10px";
div.appendChild(button);


var button2 = document.createElement("button");
button2.innerHTML = "John Wick: chapter 2";
button2.style.margin= "10px";
div.appendChild(button2);


var button3 = document.createElement("button");
button3.innerHTML = "John Wick: chapter 3";
div.appendChild(button3);

function showName(e){
  alert("you have clicked "+e.target.innerHTML);
}


div.addEventListener('click', showName, false);
```

In this code I have created 3 buttons and whenever you clicks on any button it will trigger an event showName and event.target helps us to get the element that triggered a specific event (i.e click in our case) .

and try to run console.log(event.target), this will give you the whole information about the event triggered here.

I hope this helps.